# want to make schedular that generate email notification at tha day starts

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to create a scheduler for my admin panel that generates email notification at the day

starts or some specified interval.

any link or code that is useful to create scheduler.

any idea will be Appreciated.

thanks in advance

thanks for link but in that how can i generate a code that is sends email to customer

automatically.

any idea about it than suggest me.

thanks for suggestion Hoghweed.

ok i made one admin panel for a cell phone app that used as back end for android app.

in that admin panel sales persons are registered and perform sales.

and i want one facility that send an automatic mail to the customer on the day start or

some specified day or week.

that's it.

in simple another word i want one scheduler exe that runs automatically and sens email

notification to the customer.

any help Appreciated.

thanks in Advance.

Comment: it's not easy to understand if your needs it's just about a code that automatically executes a "task" periodically, in this case at days starts, or the last one plus the code to send the email. Please, correct your question before someone down vote your question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post: [An Event Based Cron (Scheduled) Job In C#](http://bobcravens.com/2009/10/an-event-based-cron-scheduled-job-in-c/) This gives you an idea how to start implementing a scheduling application.

The article uses the [ncrontab](http://code.google.com/p/ncrontab/) library for configuring the individual schedules. I have used ncrontab for several scheduling services, too, and found it very helpful.

For sending emails you find some code in this SO thread: [How to send an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491651/how-to-send-an-email)